# pdfsharp modify pdf form

Tags: pdf, pdfsharp

I am trying to merge multiple pdfs into one using pdfsharp.  The pdf's have editable fields, but when i use the code below, and open the pdf output, the fields are not editable.
If i use "PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify" instead of "PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import" and save one pdf, it allows editable fields, but if i substitute it in the code below, i receive the error "A PDF document must be opened with PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import to import pages from it."

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (PdfDocument one = PdfReader.Open(@"C:\Websites\pdfsharpWebApplication\pdfsharpWebApplication\pdfs\Suitability.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
        using (PdfDocument two = PdfReader.Open(Server.MapPath("/pdfs/CommissionSelectionForm.pdf"), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))

        using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
        {
            CopyPages(one, outPdf);
            CopyPages(two, outPdf);
            outPdf.Save(Server.MapPath("/pdfs/file1and2.pdf"));
        }
    }

    void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
        {
            to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Since you are copying entire pdf's why worry about pages. Instead try to open them with Modify handle and combine or append them into one.

Comment: I've tried, but haven't had any success with the code.  do you have an example?

Comment: I am using this nugget's community (free) edition which I'd recommend, but you may need a paid version. https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/

Comment: my question was regarding pdfsharp.